# Running script through Terminal

Tags: steam, batch

I wonder if I can execute something in terminal, like .bat on Windows. Like, writing the script on the terminal, saving it somewhere, for example on desktop, and opening it, running automatically. I'm asking this beacuse Steam is bugged on Ubuntu 16.04, and the only way i can run this code `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam` through terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a file that would run a terminal command when you click it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106666/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-file-that-would-run-a-terminal-command-when-you-click-i)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run a command line manually and you can create `bash` shellscript files and run them like `bat` files in MSDOS and a `cmd` window in Windows. The commands in linux are very powerful.

So start a terminal window from dash or with the hotkey combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

and simply type the commands or copy and paste them into the terminal window. You can create a batch file with a text editor, gedit (graphical) or nano (text) and give it a name.

```
gedit filename
```

The name *needs no extension* (like `bat`), but you should give it execute permissions to run it easily (text after # is a comment, not used by the shell).

```
chmod ugo+x filename  # execute permisson u for user g for group and o for others
chmod +x filename     # simplified when execute permisson for everybody
```

If you want to be sure, that `bash` runs it (and no other shell), you can write the following into the first line of the shellscript file

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Now you can run it (in the current directory . (dot)) with

```
./filename
```

If you create the directory bin in your home directory

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

and move your shellscript into that directory, it will be in `PATH` and can be run from any directory with

```
filename
```

`PATH` works in the same way as in Windows.

Comment: Instead of `chmod ugo+x FILENAME` you can also just write `chmod +x FILENAME`. If none of `ugo` or `a` are specified, it assumes `a`, which equals all three of `ugo` together.

Comment: Thanks for this tip :-) I keep using the `ugo` string in order to remember it for instances, when I want separate permissions.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to launch steam in other way, but your information explanation helped me for future things.